# Which ones are the primary and secondary actions in 「Xしながら、Yする」 grammar?

Tags: grammar

Up to now, I don't understand well how I should translate

> テレビを見ながら、朝ご飯を食べる。

to English.

Some people translate it as

> A: I have breakfast while watching television.

and some other people translate it as

> B: I watch television while having breakfast.

I think there should be two actions here, one is the primary action (or job or task) and the other one is the secondary action (or job or task).

## Question

Which ones are the primary and secondary actions (or tasks, or jobs) in 「Xしながら、Yする」 grammar?

Comment: I found it related to the existing one: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27273/11192